# I would like to align my radio buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, radio-button, alignment

I was trying to do a form survey in html and css. I would like that my radio buttons will be align vertically but, Im kinda stuck because I've been trying for a while. 
Here is my code:

```
<p>Choose your education level:</p>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="1">High School degree</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="2">College degree</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="3">Masters degree</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="4">PhD degree</input>
```

---

```
and my CSS code is:

input[type=radio] {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about align vertically? By default with your code they are displayed one below the other, vertically aligned

Comment: It should also be noted that that is not the way radio buttons are written - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: Read about the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element. **It doesn't take closing tags.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
input[type=radio] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<p>Choose your education level:</p>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="1">High School degree
<br>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="2">College degree
<br>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="3">Masters degree
<br>
<input type="radio" name="education" value="4">PhD degree
```